# JSON dataset features not being loaded properly?

Tags: json, pandas, dataset, feature-selection

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

file = "/Users/mickelborg/Desktop/Dataset/2018/Carbon_Minoxide_(CO)_2018.json"

with open(file, 'r') as j:
     contents = json.loads(j.read())

oxide = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(contents, orient='index')

oxide
```

I'm trying to get a readout of the JSON dataset by the features/columns, but they don't seem to load properly.

Currently this is the output that I have:
[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAa48.png)

As can be seen from the image, the data loads incorrectly. "county_code" should each have their own row in the dataset, along with all the other following features.

What am I doing wrong in this regard?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Will you please send a link to access the JSON file? This is actually quite easy to solve, but I need to get my hands on the data.

Comment: does contents.keys() give you both ['Header', 'Data']? If so, use contents['Data'] to build your dataframe